Are the wave and the particle in QM launched simultaneously?
According to the idea of de Broglie when an electron goes from excited state to the ground state a photon is released and simultaneously a wave. But there are many experiments in Cavity quantum electrodynamics (since mid 80) where a photon emission is totally suppressed in cavities which is explained by the idea that the wave interferes negatively with its back reflected wave prohibiting the electron emitting a photon. That means that the wave is launched preliminary and exist on its own. Has the idea of de Broglie to be corrected then in sense that always a wave is starting some time before the particle?

The particle and the wave are not two separate entities; the electron has some properties that remind us of classical particles, and some properties that remind us of classical waves.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Then how is prelaunching treated?

There’s no particle, just a wave.

@Jagerber48 Why then part of it clicks in detector but the other parts don't? How can a wave disappear from click in 1 point?

@Mercury because the interaction between the wave and the detector is a local interaction despite the wave have non-local support. There isn't a wave-particle duality, but there is a measurement problem. That is, why do we only experience one term in a superposition of terms which are predicted by unitary evolution.

Are you perhaps confusing the wave representation of the quantum state of a particle such as an electron with the photon that is emitted when a electron changes from an excited state to its ground state ?

You are also mistaken. You are thinking of the photon as the wave that is emitted when the electron particle jumps from one orbital to another. When we talk about wave-particle duality, we mean that the same electron is both a particle and a wave, and the same photon is also a particle and a wave. It is not different particles and different waves.

@gandalf61 No!!

@Jagerber48 1. Is your wave probabilistic? Then as it is math there is nothing. Absurd. 2. Is it real? Then it fills a region and becomes more diluted with time. But is present in area A. When a click is found in B, the A part should superluminally rush into B. Absurd.

Quantum mechanics doesn’t care that you think it’s queer or absurd, and neither do most physicists, who are mainly interested in whether it works. In my opinion you are misrepresenting “old” QM books and have some major misunderstandings about QM.

@Ghoster i am asking a question. Can you answer and show my major misunderstandings? Or you are only interested that it works? IMO the people who are not interested why and how smth works are not physicists but engineers. And there also people who just make statements without any prove.

@Mercury: The standard of acceptance of a theory in physics is not mathematical proof. The standard, instead, is whether the theory is consistent with observed fact.

@LeeMosher Absolutely true. Is CI consistent with these facts? Just show me how? Again: Cavity transition inhibition. I can easily explain it with de Broglie interpretation with augmentation that the wave comes some amount  of time before the particle.

@Mercury: "1. [...]. Absurd. 2. [...]. Absurd." Fantastic! Now you've grasp the essence of the measurement problem. To understand this you need to take a good hard look at quantum superpositions and how states can be represented as superpositions in terms of arbitrary bases. For a measurement, the appropriate basis becomes the measurement basis which is localized. Hence, you can have a localized measurement without superluminal propagation.

@flippiefanus I don't think that a math trick can make a real thing (the real wave) (because we discuss here that there is no particles only waves) far away from point of detector to vanish completely or even change in ANYWAY.


there is no particle without wave and no wave without particle. Is this true?

The wave function "of an electron" does not describe how a single electron will behave in detail. The wave function does not describe the detailed trajectory of any single electron. In quantum mechanics, there is no way to describe the trajectory (position as a function of time) of any single electron. The best we can to in quantum mechanics is to calculate an expectation value.
The wave function is probabilistic; it describes the various possibilities of what could happen, not what does happen.
For example, in the "double slit" experiment, the squared wave function provides the probabilities that if you measure you will find the electron at a given location. The wave function does not tell you what actually will happen. The actual measured location of the electron at the detector screen is the "particle" nature of the electron; the detector registers a discrete-looking blip/blob on the detector screen. If this experiment is repeated a bunch of times then the distribution of blips/blobs will start to look like the projection of the squared wave function on the detector screen.

You can see the wave pattern emerge in the diagram in anna's answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744238/123208 https://i.sstatic.net/VV13y.jpg

All this well known and one will say trivial. You don't answer my question at all.

@Mercury OK. I guess your question is a little unclear. Which specific question was not answered?

@hft I rewrite. Do probability wave immerge simultaneously with the photon and v.v. Cavity QED shows they do not. In certain cavity atoms can not emit a  certain wavelength. Fact. This means a probability wave has traveled and got back. Math (no physics) rules the atom.

@Mercury Sorry, I still don't see what specific question you are asking that you want answered. I see you edited your post to change the word "drops" to the word "goes," but I don't see any new question. I also see you have asked a question in the comment above ("Do probability wave immerge simultaneously with the photon"), which you also seem to have immediately answered yourself ("they do not"). What is your question? Please edit it into the original post and clean up the parts that are no longer needed.

@hft If they don't appear simultaneously they are separate things contrary to wave-particle duality. Also a pr. wave can not go on its own completely because it just shows where particle can be, but the particle would not be there.

Also a pr. wave is just imagination not real thing and it can not do anything incl. reflection but most to stop an atom of emitting. So: 1. the wave is separate from the particle (no dualism) 2. the wave is real . All this is against Copenhagen interpretation. If CI is right as it stands in textbooks i dont think it can explain this.
