# Is each INDIVIDUAL photon a PHYSICAL wave?

Tags: waves, visible-light, photons, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality

Sigh.

So I've scoured the internet for many many hours, on many many occasions... aaand, yeah.

Is *light*:

1. just ONE photon which acts like a physical wave as those seen in classical mechanics (if so, where does one begin and the next stop)
2. a stream of MULTIPLE photons, each an individual, quantized, packet of energy (i.e. a "particle") — where each packet's position, in for example an interference pattern, can be described by the **purely mathematical** function of probability that for whatever reason takes the form of a wave (the wavefunction...)
3. multiple wave-like photons together making up a wave-like curve, described in the wavefunction of probability. Are their amplitudes added together or are they like a longitudinal wave in a transversal wave?

a) other interpretations? "Fields"?

b) there is no translation of the math into words. But it checks out, so physicists just stopped worrying about it...

Basically: where do you draw the line between a few photons and "10 to the power of alot" of photons? *When* do the photons start becoming a PHYSICAL wave? Or are they never this *actual* wave and it's all just probability?? Like, WHAT IS THE RELATION between the wave-particle duality and the wavefunction (and it's "collapse")?!

Any help would be unfathomably appreciated.

Comment: What experiment do you have in mind? Physics can't answer purely abstract questions.

Comment: my answer  here to a similar question may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/how-many-photons-are-needed-to-make-a-light-wave/269098#269098 .

Comment: As far as I can think, there are no particles (photons, in this case)  out of an abstract field without *observation*.  Don't blame me, I don't understand it myself and haven't seen anyone who gave me more than buzzwords. Maybe there are some masterminds out there that really understand this, but they are not willing or able to explain.

Comment: Maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273032/what-exactly-is-a-photon/273180#273180

Comment: [What are photons, EM radiation and EM waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253957)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we can only say anything about the quantum world in as far as we can make observation of it. For that reason, the underlying mechanisms that cannot be directly observed always rely on how we *interpret* the observations. So, unless we can find a logically unambiguous way to relate observations to an understanding of the underlying mechanisms, these interpretations (of which there are many) will always remain questionable.

Nevertheless, from what we do observe we can make some conclusions about the nature light. The idea of photons came from the observations of black body radiation and the photoelectric effect (among others). Based on these, Planck and Einstein (among others) concluded that light consists of quantized bits of energy. Strictly speaking, they could only make this statement conclusively about the nature of *interactions* between light and matter. In other words: light is always radiated or absorbed in such quantized bits, which came to be known as photons. The consequences is that after being produced from radiation, light must consist of such photons.

Are photons localized like classical particles? That we cannot say because whenever they are radiated or absorbed, it is the atoms or molecules from which they are radiated or by which they are absorbed that provide the localization, making these event appear as localized events. So, we can think of photons as having the same wave structure as a classical light wave would have, but having only a fixed quantized amount of energy. That is why people often refer to photons as *single excitations of the wave*.

If photons are not localized, how can they be absorbed at localized points? That is a bit more difficult to explain (getting more technical). It requires the concept of quantum superposition. Basically what happens is that the wave of a single photon can be represented as a superposition of localized wavelets, each representing the complete quantized energy of the photon, but multiplied by a complex coefficient representing the probability amplitude for that wavelet. Only the one wavelet that is aligned with the absorbing atom or molecule will be absorbed, with a probability given by the magnitude squared of the coefficient. So the notion of collapse it not necessary.

How many photons are there in an optical wave? That is easier to answer. If you measure the energy or power (energy per unit time) in the optical wave and divide it by the energy per photon you get the average number of photons (or number per unit time) in the wave. However, due to the concept of superposition, we cannot in general fix the number of photons in an optical field as an exact number.

Hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: I liked it all but superposition should not affect the number of photons in the EM field or optical field.

Comment: @PhysicsDave:  A coherent state is an example of a state consisting of the superposition of Fock states with different number of photons. That is why there is no fixed number of photons associated with a coherent state; only an average.

Answer (score -1):

This wave video should help, observe if the wave is spread or local?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su7GkqwxG08

Just ignore the hippo part, but he makes a cool localized wave.  But in all seriousness think of the photon as a localized wave in the EM field but in contrast think of an excited electron in an atom ... the EM field is perturbed virtually but in all directions (this excited state can last a long time).

In addition you are likely confused about the behaviour of mediums in which energy can travel. In an ideal medium (water not bad) if you throw a pebble in the pool you see a wave spreading ... the ideal medium never absorbs the energy, the wave would bounce off the walls and interfere, the wave energy would seem to disappear but it does not. Either the wave will reemerge or more likely the energy will be held in the elasticity of the perfect medium .... the wave needs to crash on a beach/shore to be cancelled.  The same is true if you threw many pebbles ... and you could make a nice wave if you synced your pebbles.

For the EM field we can never observe the field directly as we can with water, photons can superimpose in this field but they are produced by atoms one at time and absorbed by atoms one at a time. The EM field is elastic, energy is not lost.  If you sync your electrons in an antenna for example you can make a nice big wave .... but the energy comes out of this wave in the receiving antenna one photon at a time.

Comment: ‘ the photon as a localized wave in the EM field’
I don’t see how this can be correct even after clarification.

Comment: your video is about water waves, not electromagnetic waves which do not need a medium in order to exist. photons are elementary point   particles in mainstream physics, and build up the classical wave when in large numbers. analogy: a building is made of bricks , but bricks are not a building,

Comment: @annav photons are a particle in  the Standard Model, they are both a particle and wave in the mainstream.

Comment: @PhysicsDave the wave nature in quantum particles is seen in the **probability** distributions, which is true also for the photons of the mainstream particle standard model.